# Coherence graph blank - Coherence Value of nan

Tags: python, graph, nan, lda, mallet

Thanks for stopping by.  I was trying to get some help with this graph that is showing up blank.  I'm following this tutorial #17 https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/ to build a graph of coherence scores for different numbers of topics using LDAMallet.  Here is my code:

```html
os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:\\mallet\\mallet-2.0.8'

mallet_path = 'C:\\mallet\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet'
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs[:])
bow_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in processed_docs]



def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, bow_corpus, documents, limit, start=2, step=3):
    """
    Compute c_v coherence for various number of topics

    Parameters:
    ----------
    dictionary : Premium Billing data 
    corpus : Gensim bow_corpus
    texts : document
    limit : Max num of topics

    Returns:
    -------
    model_list : List of LDA topic models
    coherence_values : Coherence values corresponding to the LDA model with respective number of topics
    """
    coherence_values = []
    model_list = []
    for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
        model = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=dictionary)
        model_list.append(model)
        coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=model, texts=documents, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
        coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())

    return model_list, coherence_values
    
# Can take a long time to run.
model_list, coherence_values = compute_coherence_values(dictionary=dictionary, bow_corpus=bow_corpus,
                                                        documents=documents, start=2, limit=40, step=6)
                                                        
# Show graph
limit=40; start=2; step=6;
x = range(start, limit, step)
plt.plot(x, coherence_values)
plt.xlabel("Num Topics")
plt.ylabel("Coherence score")
plt.legend(("coherence_values"), loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: it's drawing a blank and so am I]

```html
# Print the coherence scores
for m, cv in zip(x, coherence_values):
    print("Num Topics =", m, " has Coherence Value of", round(cv, 4))
```

[image: nan like the bread]

The data:

[image: dictionary]

[image: bow_corpus]

[image: print stuff]

What I wish it looked like:

[image: the dream]

Pls help

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Comment: I just wrote a loop - the graph never worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in the assigned value to parameter "texts" in the function CoherenceModel. I am not sure how you define the passed value "documents", however I used the following:

```
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=[tokens], dictionary=dict, coherence='c_v')
```

I defined "tokens" as list of words. If I passed texts = tokens, it gave me nan, then when I passed it in a list as above, it works fine!

Comment: Careful: `dict` is the name of the built-in dictionary type, which you definitely don't want to overwrite with a variable name.